# What does a D&D adventure format look like?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, adventure-writing

I am writing a D&D story and I am new to the world of D&D, and wanted to make an adventure of my own. I am not quite sure how to write one though. How should I format it?  What format are D&D adventures typically written as?

Comment: Could you clarify, are you trying to write a D&D adventure/campaign for players to play through, or are you just writing a story?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Writing a D&D adventure/campaign.

Comment: Are there any more details you can give about the kind of campaign you are interested in? There are many different types of adventure styles, e.g. linear narratives where there is one narrative thread that keeps the players "on the rails" so to speak, or open world/sandbox type campaigns where the world is built and the players find the narrative conflict through exploration. These types of adventures will be formatted quite differently.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Can i show you a preview of the story? I just started and haven't gotten far.

Comment: Any details you can provide that would narrow down and clarify exactly what youre trying to do would be helpful and should be included in the question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are referring to **writing an adventure**.  This is a set of notes/maps/handouts/descriptions/statblocks that a GM can use to run a game or several games of DnD for a group of players.  What form this takes varies from person to person - there are pre-written adventures published by a variety of publishers (wizards of the coast and paizo are two notable 'DnD' ones) that follow a fairly set format - those made for personal use vary wildly and can be voluminous or extremely bare bones.

Comment: @user2754 thank you, you helped with the format of the story.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because the question is "What does a written adventure look like" and youve responded with "There are lots of ways", which is kind of an answer but not really.